# Stop overlaid rectangle receiving wpf click event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a rectangle with opacity 0 that covers a grid containing various controls. The idea is that this rectangle will fade in to hide the background controls at some point. At the moment, the rectangle is covering the controls and so you can't click on the controls as the click will be absorbed by the rectangle. Ideally, some way of completely disabling the rectangle from having any effect until the animation starts would best.

Here's a cut back version of the code I have:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Some text" />
        <Button Content="A button" Click="buttonClicked" />
    </Grid>

    <Rectangle x:Name="rectOverlay" Opacity="0" />
</Grid>
```

Cs:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

private void buttonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rectOverlay.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.OpacityProperty, new DoubleAnimation(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
}
```

Comment: Why not set the `Visibility` of Rectangle to `Collapsed`? In your buttonClicked method you could also change/animate `Visibility` property to `Visible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Visibility` of the Rectangle to `Collapsed`, so that it doesn't eat mouse clicks. And you could set it back to `Visible` in your `buttonClicked` method.

Here is what I tried:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Some text" />
        <Button Content="A button" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
    </Grid>

    <Rectangle x:Name="rectOverlay" Opacity="0" Fill="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

buttonClicked Code:

```
rectOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
rectOverlay.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.OpacityProperty, new DoubleAnimation(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
```

Comment: Cool. If it helped you can you mark it as answer, so that it helps others too.